# on select color changes

Tags: color

[image]Im getting some problem when i click the object it shows the color and when select other object or deselect the color is no more. U can c my image below how the color change on select and deselect. May i know how to fix it. I have restart blender and my machine to but yet to same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume, that in the place, where you're clicking there are 2 meshes, one with material applied and one without. When you click on the one with material it is being shown.

Comment: yes u caught it right